label report printing differently in SSRS versus VS
I have created a label report in Visual Studio that lines up perfectly to an Avery 55160 label sheet.  When I print this directly from Visual Studio onto a label sheet, it prints correctly and is lined up.
However, when I deploy this report to SSRS then try print, SSRS somehow forces the report to a PDF version that is completely out of line from the label sheet.
Is there any way to print from SSRS the same as what is produced in VS?  The user I am creating this report for does not have VS.
Further, there is a bar code on each label.  The bar code prints correctly in VS, but the PDF that prints from SSRS prints the number that is represented by the bar code (not the actual bar code).
Any help here would be greatly appreciated.
I have tried printing from SSRS in different formats but can't get it to work.

Sounds like the barcode font you're using on you VS machine is missing on the SSRS server and/or the PC it's printing from. Maybe a solution here.
